# No color in folium choropleth legend implemented in pyqt5 and tooltips not showing

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt, pyqt5, folium

I'm having 2 problems with implementing folium in a pyqt5 UI:

1. The legend in my choropleth is showing the correct numbers, but the color in the legend is not displaying.
2. The code snippet I have listed below is not showing tooltips.

The .json and data can be found here:

- https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/data/us-states.json
- https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/data/US_Unemployment_Oct2012.csv

The code to both questions is here:

```
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QFileDialog, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
import folium
import io
import pandas as pd
import os


class foliumWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        #super().__init__()
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

                  
        state_data = 'US_Unemployment_Oct2012.csv'
        us_geo = 'us-states.json'
        
        df = pd.read_csv(state_data, na_values=[" "])
     
        m = folium.Map(location=[48, -102], tiles="cartodbpositron", zoom_start=3)


        choropleth = folium.Choropleth(
            geo_data= us_geo,
            name="choropleth",
            data=df,
            columns=["State","Unemployment"],
            key_on="feature.id",
            fill_color="PuRd",
            fill_opacity=0.7,
            line_opacity=0.1,
            legend_name="Unemployment",
            reset=True,
        ).add_to(m)

        choropleth.geojson.add_child(
            folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(['State'])
            )


        #folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
        data = io.BytesIO()
        m.save(data, close_file=False)


        webView = QWebEngineView()
        webView.setHtml(data.getvalue().decode())
        layout.addWidget(webView)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An error in the code provided by the OP is that GeoJsonTooltip expects the fields of the geojson as fields, not the .csv so it throws an exception.

Eliminating redundant code you get:

```py
import io
import os
from pathlib import Path

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

import folium
import pandas as pd


class FoliumWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        current_dir = Path(__file__).resolve().parent

        state_data = "US_Unemployment_Oct2012.csv"
        us_geo = "us-states.json"

        df = pd.read_csv(str(current_dir.joinpath(state_data)), na_values=[" "])
        m = folium.Map(location=[48, -102], tiles="cartodbpositron", zoom_start=3)

        choropleth = folium.Choropleth(
            geo_data=str(current_dir.joinpath(us_geo)),
            name="choropleth",
            data=df,
            columns=["State", "Unemployment"],
            key_on="feature.id",
            fill_color="PuRd",
            fill_opacity=0.7,
            line_opacity=0.1,
            legend_name="Unemployment",
            reset=True,
        ).add_to(m)

        choropleth.geojson.add_child(folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(["name"]))

        webView = QWebEngineView()
        layout.addWidget(webView)

        data = io.BytesIO()
        m.save(data, close_file=False)
        webView.setHtml(data.getvalue().decode())


def main():
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    widget = FoliumWidget()
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent - that solved my tooltip question!  I'm still not getting color in the legend...any thoughts about what could be the cause?

Comment: @mtc555 I do not know, I could never reproduce the problem since the code you provide is not reproducible: I copied it, pasted it, added the missing elements and I got an exception that I indicated in my post, then I refactor your code and I never saw the error you indicate , my post has an image that shows both functionalities correctly.